# How can delete the data set from Google big query?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to delete entire public data set from my workspace. But i don't see any option where can delete the entire data set from the console and when i tried to delete each of set, i am getting
below error

```
Access Denied: Dataset bigquery-public-data:austin_311: Permission bigquery.datasets.delete denied on dataset bigquery-public-data:austin_311 (or it may not exist).
```

Below is the public data set reference

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOV79.png)

Comment: Click on the blue pin to 'un-pin' the project.  Note, you won't be able to unpin datasets, only at the project level.  You tried to delete someone else's data!

Answer (score 0):

`bigquery-public-data` is a public dataset and you cannot delete it.

I think you just want to `unpin` the dataset from your BigQuery console.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ryan .. so i was bit concerned about will that make any cost when it keep in the account.

Comment: @adhihari no, it doesn't cost you anything just by pinning those public dataset. But if you query those dataset, Google will start charging you after 1TB usage per month. 
Reference: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data